# remove element if it has a certain string in it

Tags: python, list

I have a list `['1 2 4 5 0.9', '1 2 4 5 0.6', '1 2 4 5 0.3', '1 2 4 5 0.4']`

I also have another list: `[0.9, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8]`

I want to use the second list and the first list elements include whats in the second list then the element gets removed, so the first list ends up like:

```
[1 2 4 5 0.6', '1 2 4 5 0.4']
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
>>> lst = ['1 2 4 5 0.9','1 2 4 5 0.6','1 2 4 5 0.3','1 2 4 5 0.4']
>>> s = set([0.9,0.3,0.7,0.8])
>>> [x for x in lst if float(x.split()[-1]) not in s]
['1 2 4 5 0.6', '1 2 4 5 0.4']
```

Comment: I think `x.rsplit(' ', 1)` is better since it allows you doing less splits than `x.split()[-1]`.

Comment: @segfolt -- that "fails" if the string ends with a space. Maybe `x.rsplit(None,1)` is a little better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more general approach to do this. I realize this may not be the best method to do this, but this was off the top of my head.

```
>>> listOne = ['1 2 4 5 0.9', '1 2 4 5 0.6', '1 2 4 5 0.3', '1 2 4 5 0.4']
>>> listTwo = [0.9, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8]
>>> finalList = []
>>> for element in listOne:
       flagBit = 0
       for number in element.split():
           if float(number) in listTwo:
               flagBit = 1
               break
       if flagBit == 0:
           finalList.append(element)
```